# How to keep the first value of a specific column after use explode() function in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with this structure:

```
ssid| ccnt|   table_read    | table_write|execution_time
123   2   [table_a,table_b]     table_c        12
456   3   [table_d,table_f]     table_g        25
```

When i use explode function for 'table_read' column, it repeats the execution time:

```
ssid| ccnt|   table_read    | table_write|execution_time
123   2        table_a          table_c        12
123   2        table_b          table_c        12
456   3        table_d          table_g        25
456   3        table_f          table_g        25
```

But i can't happen because when i summarize it, it returns the wrong result. I wish to have the following result:

```
ssid| ccnt|   table_read    | table_write |   execution_time
    123   2        table_a          table_c        12
    123   2        table_b          table_c        0
    456   3        table_d          table_g        25
    456   3        table_f          table_g        0
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After `explode` use `Series.mask` on `execution_time` to mask the duplicated values of `ssid` with a fill value of `0`:

```
d = df.explode('table_read')
d['execution_time'] = d['execution_time'].mask(d['ssid'].duplicated(), 0)
```

Or use *boolean indexing to* fill the duplicated values with `0`:

```
d.loc[d['ssid'].duplicated(), 'execution_time'] = 0
```

Result:

```
print(d)
   ssid  ccnt table_read table_write  execution_time
0   123     2    table_a     table_c              12
0   123     2    table_b     table_c               0
1   456     3    table_d     table_g              25
1   456     3    table_f     table_g               0
```